# Why isn't my loop terminating?

Tags: c++, pointers, for-loop

newbie question here, can anybody provide an answer to why this loop is not terminating? I am refrencing the address of the variable, then de-referencing it and adding one to it. By my logic it should terminate by ~  the 10th step.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int addtoi(int intern);

int main(){

    for(int i = 0; i < 10;addtoi(i)){



    }

}

int addtoi(int intern){

    int *pt;

    pt = &intern;

    ++*pt;
    cout << *pt << "\t" << intern << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all you don't really change the value of `i` in your `addtoi` method. Secondly, you need to pass `i` as a reference or make it into a pointer so that changes inside the method will be reflected outside of it

Comment: Thank you, I just realized that silly mistake :)

Comment: When you pass `i` to your function it makes a ***copy*** of it that it uses inside the function. You need to pass by *reference* or pass a pointer to `i`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop is not terminating because any changes that you made to `intern` inside `addtoi` stay inside `addtoi`. The fact that you take a pointer there has no effect, because it's too late: you are taking a pointer of a local variable, which is a copy of `i` passed in.

You can fix this by passing in `intern` by reference, like this:

```
int addtoi(int& intern) {
    intern++;
    cout << intern << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You do not need to take its address - simply modifying it will change the value of `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You don't change the value of `i` anywhere in your loop. You do pass its *value* to `addtoi`, but passing a *value* can't change the value of the variable whose value you took. So why would it ever end?

If you pass a reference or pointer to `i` to `addtoi`, then it can change `i`'s value. But if you only pass the value itself, then it can only change the value passed to it, which has no effect on `i`'s value.

What do you think would happen if you did this:

```
addtoi(1);
```

Do you think that constant `1` would somehow change? Same thing -- if you pass a value, you can't change anything in the caller since all you got was a value.

Consider:

```
int j = 1;
int i = 1;
addtoi(i);
addtoi(j);
addtoi(1);
```

These three calls all pass the same value to `addtoi`, 1. It makes no difference how you obtain that value if all you pass is the value.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much,this silly mistake just shows exactly how new I am to pointers!

Answer (score 1):

The loop is not terminating because when you do `addtoi(i)`, the value of i is send to the `addtoi()` function and not the original i variable. Its a classic example of pass by value.